# Toast flutter package decorations not applied with version 8.2.4

Tags: flutter

[Toast appear with flutter logo and decorations not applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J17fw.png)

i tried to change package version to 8.0.2 but no thing changed i want to apply green color when a toast occurs and remove flutter logo from a toast message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [contextless toast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast#toast-with-no-context) is using native methods to show the toast. The package does not have full control over the styling, so your OS might override how the toast is shown. It is still possible to customize the toast style for android by creating a custom xml for the toast ([following this instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast#custom-toast-for-android)).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/corner"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF4CAF50"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        tools:text="Toast should be short." />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

If you want to have control over the styling of the toast, you should use the [Toast with BuildContext](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast#toast-with-buildcontext-all-platforms). First, add `FToastBuilder()` to the `builder` parameter in your `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: FToastBuilder(),
  // ...
)
```

Now if you're calling the toast from a `StatelessWidget`, convert it to `StatefulWidget` first. After that, add this inside the widget state class:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late FToast fToast; // (1) Add this

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    fToast = FToast(); // (2) Instantiate the toast
    fToast.init(context); // (3) Init it with context
  }

  // ...
```

Now you can show the toast in this way:

```dart
fToast.showToast(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 20.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
    ),
    child: Text(
      'Toast Message',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]